# Average spring natrive image size

Tags: spring-boot, spring-native

I am trying to compile a springboot App to native using graalVM, the application itself has nothing in it, just the application main file, when running gradle nativeCompile, the image is about ~50Mb in size, is this the expected size ? or am i missing some optimizations ?
In the Build logs i noticed some log lines such as  :

```
========================================================================================================================
    [1/8] Initializing...                                                                                    (4.9s @ 0.24GB)
     Java version: 17.0.7+8-LTS, vendor version: Oracle GraalVM 17.0.7+8.1
     Graal compiler: optimization level: 2, target machine: x86-64-v3, PGO: ML-inferred
     C compiler: cl.exe (microsoft, x64, 19.36.32534)
     Garbage collector: Serial GC (max heap size: 80% of RAM)
     1 user-specific feature(s)
     - org.springframework.aot.nativex.feature.PreComputeFieldFeature
    Field org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter#log4jSpiPresent set to true at build time
    Field org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter#log4jSlf4jProviderPresent set to true at build time
    Field org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter#slf4jSpiPresent set to true at build time
    Field org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter#slf4jApiPresent set to true at build time
    Field org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator#imageCode set to true at build time
    Field org.springframework.boot.logging.java.JavaLoggingSystem$Factory#PRESENT set to true at build time
    Field org.springframework.core.NativeDetector#imageCode set to true at build time
    Field org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem$Factory#PRESENT set to false at build time
    Field org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem$Factory#PRESENT set to true at build time
    Field org.springframework.core.KotlinDetector#kotlinPresent set to true at build time
    Field org.springframework.core.KotlinDetector#kotlinReflectPresent set to true at build time
    Field org.springframework.format.support.DefaultFormattingConversionService#jsr354Present set to false at build time
    Field org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystemProperties#JBOSS_LOGGING_PRESENT set to false at build time
    Field org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter#reactiveStreamsPresent set to false at build time
    [2/8] Performing analysis...  [*****]                                                                   (12.9s @ 1.21GB)
      11,346 (88.27%) of 12,854 types reachable
      17,177 (67.40%) of 25,485 fields reachable
      58,937 (61.80%) of 95,367 methods reachable
       3,583 types,   134 fields, and 1,826 methods registered for reflection
          78 types,    74 fields, and    62 methods registered for JNI access
           5 native libraries: crypt32, ncrypt, psapi, version, winhttp
    [3/8] Building universe...                                                                               (1.9s @ 1.87GB)
    [4/8] Parsing methods...      [**]                                                                       (4.4s @ 1.35GB)
    [5/8] Inlining methods...     [***]                                                                      (0.5s @ 2.52GB)
    [6/8] Compiling methods...    [*****]                                                                   (28.5s @ 4.55GB)
    [7/8] Layouting methods...    [**]                                                                       (3.2s @ 2.09GB)
    [8/8] Creating image...       [**]                                                                       (3.2s @ 2.62GB)
      32.11MB (59.34%) for code area:    31,614 compilation units
      21.57MB (39.87%) for image heap:  311,575 objects and 33 resources
     440.91kB ( 0.80%) for other data
      54.12MB in total
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Top 10 origins of code area:                                Top 10 object types in image heap:
      10.81MB java.base                                            6.62MB byte[] for code metadata
       5.09MB kotlin-reflect-1.8.21.jar                            3.15MB byte[] for java.lang.String
       3.44MB java.xml                                             2.24MB java.lang.String
       3.25MB svm.jar (Native Image)                               2.02MB java.lang.Class
       2.05MB spring-core-6.0.9.jar                                1.88MB byte[] for general heap data
       1.45MB spring-boot-3.1.0.jar                              673.03kB byte[] for reflection metadata
     857.06kB spring-beans-6.0.9.jar                             531.84kB com.oracle.svm.core.hub.DynamicHubCompanion
     754.30kB logback-core-1.4.7.jar                             487.22kB java.util.HashMap$Node
     623.80kB spring-expression-6.0.9.jar                        397.81kB java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node
     391.42kB kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21.jar                           320.75kB c.o.svm.core.hub.DynamicHub$ReflectionMetadata
       3.23MB for 46 more packages                                 2.94MB for 2231 more object types
```

Are there any knows optimizations that i can add ? or this is the normal behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

running java 21 and spring boot 3.1.5 it is roughly the same, maybe a bit higher, so guess you're doing fine, may follow optimizations suggested at the end:

```
[8/8] Creating image...       [***]                                                                     (10,2s @ 2,01GB)
  31,71MB (56,71%) for code area:    32.507 compilation units
  23,76MB (42,48%) for image heap:  311.811 objects and 166 resources
 462,61kB ( 0,81%) for other data
  55,92MB in total
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Top 10 origins of code area:                                Top 10 object types in image heap:
  15,52MB java.base                                            8,62MB byte[] for code metadata
   4,03MB svm.ja r (Native Image)                               3,97MB byte[] for java.lang.String
   3,21MB java.xml                                             2,17MB java.lang.String
   2,13MB tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar                        1,90MB java.lang.Class
   1,41MB spring-core-6.0.13.jar                             809,35kB byte[] for embedded resources
 748,35kB spring-beans-6.0.13.jar                            797,79kB byte[] for general heap data
 567,90kB java.management                                    649,98kB byte[] for reflection metadata
 528,18kB spring-expression-6.0.13.jar                       513,98kB com.oracle.svm.core.hub.DynamicHubCompanion
 524,89kB spring-boot-3.1.5.jar                              372,56kB java.util.HashMap$Node
 348,40kB java.rmi                                           309,50kB c.o.svm.core.hub.DynamicHub$ReflectionMetadata
   2,52MB for 36 more packages                                 3,73MB for 2419 more object types
      For more details, open 'D:\projects\native\target\native-build-report.html'.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Security report:
 - Binary includes Java deserialization.
 - Use '--enable-sbom' to embed a Software Bill of Materials (SBOM) in the binary.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Recommendations:
 PGO:  Use Profile-Guided Optimizations ('--pgo') for improved throughput.
 HEAP: Set max heap for improved and more predictable memory usage.
 QBM:  Use the quick build mode ('-Ob') to speed up builds during development.
Print of Dashboard dump output ended.
```